# JS изменение способа запуска ф-ии

Tags: javascript, html, css

Уточните как нужно изменить код чтоб его можно было запустить при загрузке страницы, а не после нажатия на кнопу. С JS знаком как потребитель не больше, судя по коду слушается нажатие на кнопарь, вызывается ф-я, потом кнопарь CSS-м затирается, но так нудно не нужно)

```
    <script>
    (function() {
        var headline = document.querySelector('.trigger-headline'),
            trigger = document.querySelector('.btn--trigger'),
            segmenter = new Segmenter(document.querySelector('.segmenter'), {

                onReady: function() {
                    trigger.classList.remove('btn--hidden');
                    trigger.addEventListener('click', function() {
                        segmenter.animate();
                        headline.classList.remove('trigger-headline--hidden');
                        this.classList.add('btn--hidden');
                    });
                }
            });
    })();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Если не нужно нажатие, то удалите "навешивание" слушателя и всё

```
(function() {
    var headline = document.querySelector('.trigger-headline'),
        trigger = document.querySelector('.btn--trigger'),
        segmenter = new Segmenter(document.querySelector('.segmenter'), {
            onReady: function() {
                trigger.classList.remove('btn--hidden');
                segmenter.animate();
                headline.classList.remove('trigger-headline--hidden');
                //this.classList.add('btn--hidden');

            }
        });
})();
```

Answer (score 0):

Вроде как то так.

```js
(function() {
        var headline = document.querySelector('.trigger-headline'),
            trigger = document.querySelector('.btn--trigger'),
            segmenter = new Segmenter(document.querySelector('.segmenter'), {

                onReady: function() {
                    trigger.classList.remove('btn--hidden');
                    function triggerPlay() {
                        segmenter.animate();
                        headline.classList.remove('trigger-headline--hidden');
                        this.classList.add('btn--hidden');
                    });
                    triggerPlay();
                }
            });
    })();
```